# How to get a Touch object from a TouchEvent

Tags: javascript, html, dom, touch

Looking at [mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) for TouchEvent, I see no obvious way to get the (one) Touch object that caused the event. Maybe this is because I'm misunderstanding how these things work. If the following were true, it would make sense to me:

- If multiple touch events of the same type happen, the event handler is called only once and the programmer is expected to handle the multiple events by using TouchEvent.changedTouches
- Touch events of different types will always call two different handlers separately (eg. if a touchstart happens at the same time as a touchend)

Is my guess correct? If so, then the answer to my main question would simply be to loop through the changedTouches and handle each separately (unless you have some special logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'touchstart' event is fired with a list of changedTouches, which can be 1 or many. Your guess is correct, you would have to loop through the changedTouches and treat them separately. Take a look at another portion of their documentation where they provide examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events#Tracking_new_touches

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use touch events in some complex way you could try http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/ this FastClick library, it helped to me when i was trying to get an id from touched element, it transforms all touch events to click